# Bottle cap burst phenomenon

Tags: pressure, air, evaporation

There is a trick you can do with a simple plastic water bottle: After putting the cap on as tight as you can, you twist the body of the bottle a few times so that it compresses the air in the bottle. Then, when you twist the cap off, it jumps off forward with some speed and vapors come out of the bottle (especially if there is water inside) for a short period of time. What phenomenon makes the cap pop out and why do vapors come out?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4qIlMvEZZs

Comment: An image or video might be useful, I've not seen this effect before.

Comment: Is there something else I sould do to reopen the question?

Comment: @DanielTork - I've edited the question after watching the video, and the edit actually answers the first of your questions.